# JavaScript (jquery) append issue with IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, append

im using jquery to add a quickmenue to my website.
my source code is like this :

```
var span = $('body').append('<span id="quickmenu">');
       $('#quickmenu').css('position','fixed')
              .css('background-color','white')
              .css('border','4px solid black')
              .css('border-left','0px solid black')
              .css('top','15px')
              .css('left','0px')
              .css('font-family','Calibri')
              .css('font-size','14px')
              .css('line-height','0px')
              .css('color','#777777')
              .css('text-align','center');
```

My problem on that is, everything works really fine in FF and Chrome, but IE9 isn't showing anything to me.

So i tried some alerts() after accessing the above code...:

```
alert('I run'); // I run
alert(span); // [object Object]
alert($("#quickmenu")); // [object Object] 
alert(span == $("#quickmenu")); // false
```

So i seems to be created , but not shown?!

I really have no idea what went wrong there,.... Console shows no errors in FF and IE9

Any ideas ?! :-/

Comment: I imagine this is more of a CSS styling issue. Also, you should put all those `.css()` calls into 1 class in a stylsheet and use `.addClass()`

Comment: Check document mode for IE9. If IE9 works not in standard mode and no proper `<!DOCTYPE>` directive in page it can not support `position:fixed`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531140%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: hey guys, thanks a lot at first...

1. i cant use real css options because i only have access to a <script> </script> area. 
2. the document seems to have no doctype set. its an output of Word2007 as html and im accessing the script tab over some VBscript (yeah know thats real shit, but seems to work till now ;-) )


Maybe im able to access the file again and write a dotype in the first line of the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the code is running too early. You need to wrap your code in the document ready function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

//your code goes here

});
```

I would in fact change your function to something like below:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {   
    var span = $('<span id="quickmenu" >')
        .css({
            'position':'fixed',
             'background-color':'white',
             'border':'4px solid black',
             'border-left':'0px solid black',
             'top':'15px',
             'left':'0px',
             'font-family':'Calibri',
             'font-size':'14px',
             'line-height':'0px',
             'color':'#777777',
             'text-align':'center'
        })
        .appendTo($("body"));
});
```

Comment: yeah great one, I'm (we) are really close to the answer. after changing the code to 

`$('<span id="quickmenu"></span>').appendTo($("body")); ` 
it works fine.... 
just changing the event managing doesn't work ... but now it is shown (at least at bottom of the document and not fixed) but that can maybe the issue listed in comments above with not strict document type ?!

Comment: After reading in a comment above that you can not use a class I have put all of your css properties into an object and applied them in one go, and then appended the span to the body. Try the edited answer that I have provided.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works fine ;-) just the fixed issue, but thats an other problem ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As Smoki pointed out in the comments.

Switching from: `$("#target").append(my_dom_element);`

to: `my_dom_element.appendTo("#target");`

Seems to solve the issue.

I was using a large but unscripted element that I was importing from an external file and turning into an element in advance.  Then the append would fail.  Switching to using the `.appendTo()` method worked.  So I would hazard a guess that the IE code for `.append()` gets confused when asked to append complex elements.  Though it could just as easily be what it was appending it to that confused it.

(jQuery 1.8.2)